# How to update spawnpoint/checkpoint in 3D unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm Currently trying to develop a respawn system, but I can't seem to update the checkpoint.

The code has these objectives

-To respawn the player when their health is 0

-To update the checkpoint when the player steps on a new savepoint(anchor) objects

I can't seem to update the savepoint(anchor) when the player steps on it and they go back to the original spawn point when the player dies.

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;   

public class ResetPlayer : MonoBehaviour  {
         public float playerHeight;
         public float playerHealth;
 
     [Header("Border")]
     public LayerMask whatIsBorder;
     public bool touchBorder;
 
     [Header("Save Point")]
     public LayerMask whatIsSavePoint;
     public bool touchAnchor;
 
     Vector2 p_resetPosition;
 
     Rigidbody rb;
 
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
 
         touchBorder = false;
         touchAnchor = false;
 
         p_resetPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         // border check 
         touchBorder = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsBorder);
 
         // anchor check (should respawn player to the respected anchor)
         touchAnchor = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsSavePoint);
     }
 
     private void FixedUpdate()
     {
         Reset_Player();
         PlayerToSpawnpoint();
         ResetPlayerFromBorder();
     }
 
     // Condition to reset player - when player is dead
     private void Reset_Player()
     {
         if(playerHealth is 0)
         {
             playerHealth = playerHealth + 100;
 
             TransportPlayer();
         }
     }
 
     // if the player touches the border of the world they die
     private void ResetPlayerFromBorder()
     {
         if (touchBorder)
         {
             playerHealth = playerHealth - playerHealth;
             Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " touched Border");
         }
     }
 
     // To check if a player has steped on a save point (anchor) and update the players respawn point
     private void PlayerToSpawnpoint()
     {
         if (touchAnchor)
         {
             Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " touched Anchor");
         }
     }
 
     // transport player to respawn point
     private void TransportPlayer()
     {
         if (touchAnchor)
         {
             // I know this doesn't work, but I hope this gives you an idea of my problem
             rb.transform.position = touchBorder.transform.position;
         }
 
         else
         {
             //Resets the player the start position
             rb.transform.position = p_resetPosition;
 
             //Resets the player the start Rotation
             rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
         }
         
     }  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not saving a reference or position to the new checkpoint. `Physics.Raycast` only returns a bool whether it hit something. It would be better to add a collider to your player. The simplest way to do this would be to use `Physics.OverlapSphere`:

```cs
// Store a reference to the current checkpoint
Transform currentCheckpoint;

// Check for colliding checkpoints
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(
    transform.position, 
    playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, 
    whatIsSavePoint
);

// Overwrite checkpoint if we collided
if (hitColliders.Count) currentCheckpoint = hitColliders[0].transform;
```

Define your `currentCheckpoint` to a default value in `Start()`, and put the collision code in update. Note that this will also overwrite the current checkpoint if the player goes back to the previous checkpoint.